# the code print out a series of nonsense number

Tags: c++

so, i'm leaning oop,  and the problem is to insert head
what i expected: 3 2 1 
what it print out: 1746464
i don't know what those number mean, can someone point out where my code went wrong, i would be very glad, thanks for reading
and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class node
{
private:
    int value;
    node *pnext;
    node *phead;

public:
    node ()
    {
        pnext=  NULL;
        phead= NULL;
    }
    node* inserthead(int b);
    void print();
};
node* node::inserthead(int _value)
{
    node *p= new node ;
    value = _value;
    pnext = phead;
    phead =p;
    return phead;
}
void node:: print ()
{
    node* p = phead;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->value << endl;
        p= p -> pnext;
    }
}
int main()
{
    node a;

    a. inserthead(1);
    a. inserthead(2);
    a. inserthead(3);
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use one class to represent both a single node and the entire list. Use two classes, one for a node (could use a struct), and one for a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
node* node::inserthead(int _value)
{
    node *p= new node ;
    value = _value;
    pnext = phead;
    phead =p;
    return phead;
}
```

sets the `value` and `next` in the root node, not the `node` being added, so the value goes into the wrong spot and the `node`s aren't linked. When you try to print, the program prints the uninitialized `value` in the last node added. The rest of the nodes were lost.

Instead use

```
node* node::inserthead(int _value)
{
    node *p= new node ;
    p->value = _value; // new node gets value
    p->pnext = phead; // new node gets linked.
    phead =p;
    return phead;
}
```